# Is there a way to send response from server even if no callback is provided from client side?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, npm, socket.io

### Issue clarification

When we use `.emit()` or `.send()` and we also want to confirm message reception (so called *[acknowledgements](https://socket.io/docs/#Sending-and-getting-data-acknowledgements)*) we simply write something like this:

```
socket.emit('someEvent', payload, callback);
```

What this question is all about is a `callback` part. That's the great stuff as it allows to generally send back some data as a response with no extra events emitted. All that server needs to do is to handle the request in a proper way:

```
socket.on('someEvent', (payload, callback) => { 
   doSomeStuff(); 
   callback(someData);
);
```

That works just fine when we deal with a success case. But what shall we do in these cases:

1) Callback was not sent from the client side / callback's not a function and there's a need to respond from the server side with something like *'Error: no callback is provided. Usage: ...'*

Example:

Client side - `socket.emit('someEvent');` or `socket.emit('someEvent', 1);`

Server side - `socket.on('someEvent', callback => callback());`

or

2) While handling the request something went wrong (e.g. an unsuccessful validation result) and we need to report this in a way like: *'No payload is provided or it is invalid'*

Example:

Server side -

```
socket.emit('someEvent', payload, callback => { 
   checkPayload(); 
   callback(someData); 
});
```

Client side - `socket.on('someEvent', invalidPayload, callback);`

**Question**: is there a mechanism to create custom callback from responder's side?

### My workings and workarounds

1) As for the missing callback or that one which is not a function I've concluded that I can only validate it and then invoke it only in case of its validity. So the server side is undergoing some changes:

`socket.emit('someEvent', callback => callback instanceof Function && callback()); //check callback correctness`

**Pros**: there won't be an internal error if a callback is not a function as expected.

**Cons**: in case of invalid callback a client won't be noticed about it.

2) As for the case when we need to send some error back I've only found a workaround to return a specific, agreed in advance, falsy value like `null` so that it means that no data can be returned.

```
socket.emit('someEvent', payload, callback => {  
   checkPayload();
   callback(someData || null); //send falsy, error-like value instead
});
```

**Pros**: a client will be noticed about some error by getting `null`.

**Cons**: from server side there's no simple middleware function that validates the input data and returns error **before** the main logic is being executed.

I've thought about middlewares for reaching the needed functionality, but there's no, so to say, 'event level middlewares' yet, only on the whole [namespace](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#namespace-use-fn) and [socket](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#socket-use-fn) levels. Shall I try to filter events by their names on the socket level to attach the needed functionality and send error in a way like `next(new Error(...));`? In this case there can be a work with `error` event listening, I guess.

---

[`socket.io`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io) / [`socket.io-client`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-client) versions used: **2.3.0**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) Callback was not sent from the client side / callback's not a function and there's a need to respond from the server side with something like 'Error: no callback is provided. Usage: ...'

The client and server have to agree how to do this.  If the client doesn't provide a callback, then the server argument will be `undefined` so you can detect that from the server.

So, the proper way to do it is this:

```
// client 
socket.emit('someMsg', someData, function(response) {
    console.log(`Got ${response} from server`);
});

// server
io.on('connection', socket => {
    socket.on('someMsg', (data, fn) => {
        console.log(`Got data ${data} from client, sending response`);
        // if client wants a response, send the response
        if (fn) {
            fn("got your data");
        }
    });
});
```

So, if the client does not pass the callback, then `fn` on the server side will be `undefined`.  So, you are correct to test for that before calling it.

> 2) As for the case when we need to send some error back I've only found a workaround to return a specific, agreed in advance, falsy value like null so that it means that no data can be returned.

Yes, you have to agree in advance how to send an error back.  The cleanest way to send an error back would probably be to wrap your response in an object and use a `.error` property on that object.

```
// client 
socket.emit('someMsg', someData, function(response) {
    if (response.error) {
        console.log(`Got error ${response.error} from server`);
    } else {
        console.log(`Got data ${response.data} from server`);
    }
});

// server
io.on('connection', socket => {
    socket.on('someMsg', (data, fn) => {
        console.log(`Got data ${data} from client, sending response`);
        // if client wants a response, send the response
        if (fn) {
            // no error here
            fn({error: null, data: "Got your message"});
        }
    });
});
```

What you're seeing here is that socket.io is not really a request/response type protocol and socket.io has tried to shoehorn in a bit of a response around which you have to build your own structure.

Or, you can send an error object if there's an error:

```
// server
io.on('connection', socket => {
    socket.on('someMsg', (data, fn) => {
        console.log(`Got data ${data} from client, sending response`);
        // if client wants a response, send the response
        if (fn) {
            // send an error here
            fn({error: new Error("xxx Error")});
        }
    });
});
```

> From server side there's no simple middleware function that validates the input data and returns error before the main logic is being executed.

I don't really understand what you're trying to use middleware for or to validate?  the only place this data is present is on your message handler so any server-side validation you want to do on what the client sent needs to be there.  You can certainly do that validation before you've send a response.

> Shall I try to filter events by their names on the socket level to attach the needed functionality and send error in a way like next(new Error(...));? In this case there can be a work with error event listening, I guess.

Socket.io doesn't work like Express and I don't really see why you'd try to make it work that way.  There is no `next()` involved in receiving a socket.io message so I'm not sure what you're trying to do there.  There is an option for middleware when the socket.io connection is first made, but not for subsequent messages sent over that connection.

> Is there a way to send response from server even if no callback is provided from client side?

If the client does not provide a callback, then the only way to send a response back to the client would be to send another message.  But, the whole point of sending a response is if you have a cooperating client that is listening and expecting a response so the client may as well use the callback if they want the response.  If the client doesn't want the response and won't code anything to receive it, there's nothing you can do about that.

Comment: @HlibDerbenov - Did this answer your question?

Comment: So to sum up: 1) It is useless to force the server to respond when no callback is provided (as it is simply impossible and also propably does not fit into the concept of websockets and acknowledgements) and 2) It is possible to attach an error-like information to the server's response (but only if the client wants to get the response). Do I understand you correctly?

Comment: @HlibDerbenov - Yes.  It's just like any API really.  If the client doesn't configure itself to see the response or error code, then there's no way for the server to make it do something it isn't coded to do.  But really, it's the client's responsibility to follow the API, the way the server designs it and documents it.  If the client chooses not do the right thing, that's the client's own problem, not the server's problem.  If the client chooses to ignore error responses, then that's just bad client code.  Nothing you can do about it.

Comment: @HlibDerbenov - It's no different than a client using Google's calendar API to submit a new calendar event and the client isn't coded to recognize an error response and fails to realize when a new calendar event did not get added and returned an error.  It's just bad client code - nothing Google can do about it.